# Build a long string from words in a For Loop

Tags: python

I would like to form a long sentence using a for loop in python.
I have data that came from sys.stdin and i would like to form a long sentence from the words that came from stdin.

For example,assume the words that cam from sys.stdin were

```
hello
to
all
developers
```

My current program reads as:

```
word = ''
for k in sys.stdin:
  sentence = word + ',' + k
  print(sentence)
```

I have also tried this approach:

```
for k in sys.stdin:
   word = ''
   sentence = word + ',' + k
   print(sentence)
```

All the above codes gives me the output;

```
,hello
,to
,all
,developers
```

But I need an output as;

```
hello,to,all,developers
```

Please Note; I NEED THE VARIABLE 'sentence' INSIDE THE LOOP BECAUSE IT WILL BE RE-USED IN THE LOOP LATER.

Any help please? Thank you for your input.

Comment: Does it *need* to be a for loop? Maybe `print(', '.join(sys.stdin))`? or `print(*sys.stdin, sep=", ")`?

Comment: You are forgetting that sys.stdin output contains "\n" newlines,

Comment: Even with your approach, he would get the same wrong output

Answer (score 1):

Not as familiar with for loops in python, but maybe you could try putting the "print(sentence" outside of the for loop, because print() is always going to make a new line

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
word = ''
for k in sys.stdin:
  word = word + ',' + k
print(word)
```

You need to modify `word`, you were creating another variable each time inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = ','.join(k for k in sys.stdin)
```

Comment: ```sentence = ','.join(k for k in sys.stdin).replace('\n','')```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import sys

sentence = []
for k in sys.stdin:
    if "\n" in k: # sys.stdin input contains newlines, remove those first
        sentence.append(k[:-1]) # removes the \n (newline literal) before adding to sentence list
    else:
        sentence.append(k)

print(",".join(sentence)) # converts the list of words into one long string separated with commas
```

My approach to this contains one key step that other answers are missing, which is removing the newline `"\n"` from `sys.stdin` input.
When you try this code snippet, you'll get your output in one line.

Comment: I do not want to put the data in a list before performing the operation. I want the data to remain strings so if you could modify your approach I would appreciate. --fr4nkl1n

Answer (score 0):

You can use your approach

```
word = ''
for k in sys.stdin:
  sentence = word + ',' + k
  print(sentence)
```

just add

```
sentence = sentence.replace('\n','')[1:]
```

after the loop